# How to filter nodes with taxonomy term field in a view embedded on a node?

Tags: views, ubercart, nodes

I developing a Mp3 store with Ubercart 3. I have created an "Album" content type. I have another content Type called "Song". I want to embed a View within the "Album" node that will retrieve all songs belonging to that album. This is the preview of the "Songs" View http://www.housescent.co.za/files/songz.PNG , which I wish to attach to the "Album" node. Like in this video tutorial at 9:50 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0CHC8I9xZIg

Basically I wish to mimic something like iTunes when viewing an album.

P.S. I have installed the EVA: Entity Views Attachment Module and View Field Module but I have never used it. I'm also using Pathauto.

Comment: You have two content types - 'Album' & 'Song'. Each 'Album' will have one or more 'Song'. So, it seems instead of considering 'Taxonomy' approach, if you consider 'Entity Reference' approach, it will be more cleaner.

Comment: If you consider 'Entity Reference' approach, then create a views page with 'CONTEXTUAL FILTER' as the 'Album ID' which you can pass through URL using a path like 'ANY_SUITABLE_NAME/%'. Use filter as 'Content: Type (= Album)'. Also, make sure to have a 'Entity Reference: Referencing entity' relationship to get information of 'Song' CT in the 'Fields' section.

Comment: @djs I agree Taxonomy are not the best approach, but I'm using pathauto, so my urls do not carry an ID. I was looking at the https://drupal.org/project/Viewfield as well, just not sure how to use it.

Comment: @djs I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: Can you pls give some details on the view which lists the songs 'http://www.housescent.co.za/files/songz.PNG', like the filters you have used? Also, pls give some details on the Taxonomy work flow you have used (as in the updated question that section is not available).

Comment: @djs I edited the question,see here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/80245/revisions Im not using taxonomy anymore.

Comment: @djs I'm using the ViewField Module https://drupal.org/project/Viewfield I'm stuck at the 4th instruction, I have done all other instructions from here  https://drupal.org/node/1210142

Comment: @djs I have achieved it :-) I got what I wanted. it possible to this another way, not using Views, a more static way? Im trying to avoid a huge performance hit. Thanks